# Reset rolling sum to 0 after reaching the threshold

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to compute a running total and reset it to 0 based on 2 conditions or if the limit is reached.

Here is an example.

[image: Table]

As in the image above, I need to get the running total while the following conditions are met:

1. monthly discount = 0 and monthly ticket=1

   If one of discount=1 and ticket=0, the next value for running total has to be 0.
2. running_total<50

   If running total>=50, the value for running total has to start from the value on the same row.

Here is what I'm trying to do now:

Is there any possibility to do this in HIVE? Thank you so much!!!

```
SELECT * ,
       SUM(tag_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY account, flg_sum
                      ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
       AS running_sum
FROM
  ( SELECT * ,
           SUM(CASE
                   WHEN tag_flg>=50 THEN value
                   ELSE tag_flg
               END) OVER (PARTITION BY account
                          ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) 
           AS flg_sum
   FROM
     ( SELECT * ,
              CASE
                  WHEN month_disc =0
                       AND month_ticket = 1 THEN value
                  ELSE 0
              END AS tag_flg
      FROM source_table) x) y
```

Comment: Unfortunately, solving this problem requires a recursive CTE (or similar functionality) and I don't think Hive supports that.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not quitting yet. :) I'm trying to do it in multiple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I managed to do it:

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(case when month_disc=1 OR month_ticket=0 then 0 else value end) OVER (PARTITION BY account, flg_sum, band_sum ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS running_sum
 FROM (
    SELECT *,
           FLOOR(SUM(case when month_disc=1 OR month_ticket=0 then 0 else value end) OVER (PARTITION BY account, flg_sum ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)/50.000001) as band_sum ---- create bands for running total
 FROM (
    SELECT *,
          SUM(tag_flg) OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS flg_sum
 FROM (
    SELECT *,
          CASE WHEN  (month_disc=1 OR month_ticket=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tag_flg ---- flag to count when the value is reset due to one of the conditions
    FROM source_table) x ) y) z
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the 40, 60 and 20 that aren't being accounted for matter at all in your report? Like would you want them to be counted then a new row added with a total of 0 to restart?

Comment: If the running total is reset due to one of this conditions: discount=1 and ticket=0, the new running total is 0. If the running total is reset because it reached the limit, the new running total has to be equal to Value. Thank you!